# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, on Oracle 10 and not on Oracle 11

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, ora-00907

Why the following query fails on Oracle 10 an not on Oracle 11.

```
SELECT trunc(DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 10, high =>50)) from dual;
```

Oracle 10:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit speculative, but one possible explanation for the missing right parentheses error is that this error is not really about missing parentheses.  Instead, if the API for `DBMS_RANDOM.value` is different in your version of Oracle 10 vs. Oracle 11 then you could be seeing this error.  Try this query instead:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(10, 50))
FROM dual
```

If this works, then you will know that the API has changed between Oracle 10 and 11.

Here is a [reference](http://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3341051/Generating-random-numbers-and-strings-in-Oracle.htm) which uses the API as I have in my query.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [new feature in 11gR1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO06944):

> Beginning in this release, it is now possible to invoke the function
>   in a SQL statement. For example, named notation syntax is:
>
> ```
> SELECT f(pn=>3, p2=>2, p1=>1) FROM dual
> ```
>
> Or, mixed notation is:
>
> ```
> SELECT f(1, pn=>3) FROM dual
> ```
>
> In previous releases, attempting named or mixed notation resulted in
>   an error.

So prior to 11g you could only call a PL/SQL function from SQL using positional notation, e.g.

```
SELECT trunc(DBMS_RANDOM.value(10, 50)) from dual;
```

... as @TimBiegeleisen has already shown works. The 'missing right parenthesis' error doesn't necessarily mean your parentheses are unbalanced; just that the parser saw something it didn't expect where it thought a parenthesis might go - in this case, at the `=>`.